# Controlling a 12V solenoid with N-Channel mosfet

Tags: arduino, mosfet, esp32, solenoid

I use an N-channel mosfet to switch on or off a solenoid valve that uses DC 12V, 0.25A. This is the circuit I use.

Initially I used IRFZ44N and 1N4007, but they were too big for my application, so I looked for a smaller package and now I use AO3416 and 1N4001.

**AO3416**
VDS : 20V
ID (at VGS=4.5V) 6.5A
RDS(ON) (at VGS=4.5V) < 22mΩ

This worked well, so I'm using this circuit for other parts that use 12V, as shown below.

- DC 12V, bldc motor. 0.4A
- DC 12V, led strip. 1.1A

For the LED, I also send a PWM signal to control the brightness.
It's been working well for me, but at some point I started to wonder if it's okay to use the same in these three cases. In my experience, I haven't had any major heating or problems, but I'm wondering if the circuit is electrically correct and if I'm using the right parts, so I'm posting it here.

Any advice from you guys would be greatly appreciated.
Some people have told me that you don't need a Schottky diode to control anything on 12 volts with 12 volts of DC, so I was wondering if that's true.

[image]

Comment: What's the Arduino output voltage? 5V or 3.3V?

Comment: I can't see a Schottky diode. Where would you be putting it?

Comment: I am m using esp32, therefore output voltage is 3.3V. I thought I am using D15 as a Schottky diode to prevent  reverse current protection, am I wrong?

Comment: @aquaism to be clear diode is back EMF protection, which saves your MOSFET. You are using MOSFETs as switches, so major heating will be from switching states (Vgsth is near 1V for this MOSFETs). Also this MOSFETs have some minor input capacitance, which acts as short when starting switching states. Consider puttig series resistance to save your ESP32 outputs. Put resistor to gate after R17, you can calculate proper value according to RC time of resulting circuit

Comment: Schottky is a type of diode that has a low forward voltage. The name is not related to the way it's used.